# Angular repo for multiple dependent apps and styling

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, angular-library

I am developing an app which is growing beyond my initial expectations and needs to have a satellite app for administrative purposes. The initial app is built with angular-cli and has some components, services, directives, guards, pipes and *styling* which has to be shared with the *other new* app. I understand that since Angular 6 there is a way (aka libraries, projects) to re-use certain components and services as a library. This is a migration process I am about to embark on (and it is an unnerving experience already).

What about SCSS and styling? None of the components have their own styles – it was a decision I made very early on and kept my SCSS structured in an appropriate way (with variables, mixins, etc) to style everything in the app. Now if I split the existing app in two – a shared library and an application – and then add another *new* application, how can I share existing SCSS between the two applications? If there is no way to do this – how would you go about it?

Comment: Consider using Nx or Nx practices when dealing with a monorepo style app: https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/nx-and-cli. They have guidelines on how to deal with this: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples. They created a shared library called styles, that is used in all of the apps

Comment: I am not so keen on using third party packages for keeping the whole project going. Just plain paranoia. So you are saying there are no native angular tools to achieve this?

Comment: Nx is technically just an Angular CLI project with some helpers. So you can achieve the same with just the Angular CLI, but im just advocating to follow the Nx principles. So in your case, with the Angular CLI, create a new library called `styles` and have allt he shared `scss` in there